# Scala missing parameter type for expanded function

Tags: scala

The following code doesn't compile:

```
def f[T](conv: Option[String => T]) {}
f(Some(_.toInt))
```

with `<console>:13: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.toInt)`

Of course, explicit type makes it fine:

```
scala> f(Some((x: String) => x.toInt))
```

Why the compiler can't infer String type here? Is there some kind of ambiguity?

In general, is it possible to check and examine manually the generated code from underscore expansion?

Comment: @slouc, post it as an asnwer - it's a correct one. If OP created some type classes that involved some variance or inheritance related to the `String` then it maybe would be able to infer it in some cases but otherwise you could just pass some `ClassWithoutToInt` and it cannot infer it with underscore,

Comment: @sebszyller I just deleted my comment because I think it's wrong :) how do you then explain the fact that if it weren't for the Option, that is, if method was only taking a function String => T, you could pass f(_.toInt) and it would work?

Comment: @slouc I don't know what your answer was, but hopefully mine explains why it would work.

Comment: SO complains that don't boost enough questions. I agree that by common intuition, this should just work. Of course, I may be wrong for good reasons.

Comment: Use `f(_.toInt) // show` in REPL or `-Xprint:typer` to see how typer sees your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem (I believe) is that when typing `Some(_.toInt)`, the compiler needs to infer the type parameter of `Some.apply[A](x: A)`, and to do that, it first needs to typecheck the arguments. So `_.toInt` is typechecked with `A` (considered as an unknown type constant) as expected type. This fails, because anonymous functions are only allowed not to specify parameter types when the expected type is a function type (or starting with Scala 2.12, a Single Abstract Method type). Then the compiler tries again with `undefined` as the expected type, and fails for the same reason.

In this case, the expected return type would actually be sufficient to determine the type parameter, and then this would allow to typecheck `_.toInt`, but that's not how it is designed to work.

The gory details, if you want them, are in http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html, paragraphs 6.6, 6.23, and 6.26.4.

Comment: This is slouc's original answer extended with the `apply` add-on. It's on point, imo.

Comment: *anonymous functions are only allowed not to specify parameter types when they are given by the expected type.* What does "when they are given by the expected type" mean?

Comment: Yeah, well anyways this is a much more thorough explanation. Mine was more of a hunch. Thx Alexey

Comment: Not an expert in 6.26.4, but it's not obvious to me that the anon fun can't contribute a var to the constraints: `Some[b](_.toInt) <: Option[String => a]` or `Some[b](c => Int) <: Option[String => undefined]`. The args are typechecked with expected type (but type params fixed). Hence our intuition that it's just a limitation.

Comment: So, to restore the full picture, the following happens:
1) The compiler sees `f()` and tries to determine it's type, it doesn't know it yet;
2) To do that, it goes ahead and sees `Some` and tries to determine it's type;
3) To do that, it goes ahead and sees `_.toInt`. In order to infer `_`'s type, the compiler needs to know type of `f`, which is still unknown.
4) We have a deadlock.  Am I get it right? Note that specifying `f`'s type explicitly works: `f[Int](Some(_.toInt))`.  

I also would like to see an elaboration on "when they are given by the expected type", as Yuval asked.

Comment: @som-snytt Do you mean it isn't obvious why it can't contribute in the current scheme described in 6.26.4 or why it couldn't contribute if a different approach were used?

Comment: @ars I've clarified a bit. But the curious thing is that according to my current understanding of specification, `f[Int](Some(_.toInt))` "should" fail for the same reason. So either I misunderstand it, or the compiler does the right thing but not the strictly legal one and its workaround just happens not to work for the original question.

Comment: Yes, I mean the first: I don't know why it stops and doesn't try to solve for c. (Or why it doesn't introduce c.) Also yes, `f[Int]` works because `Some[a](_.toInt)` is typechecked with expected `Option[String => Int]`. The expected type is how constraints are propagated. That's from reading the spec, not code.

Comment: @som-snytt Right, but the constraints only appear on the second step. The first step ("One computes first the types `Sj` of the argument expressions `dj`, using two alternative schemes") doesn't use the expected type and doesn't involve any constraints, and I thought it was this step which fails.

Comment: The examples show the first step produces the constraints to solve. The `undefined` bit means you can't fail with variables in play. But I'll update you if I achieve higher insight. Meanwhile, plus one.

Comment: @som-snytt Can't you? 6.23.1 doesn't say explicitly what happens when the expected type of a function literal is `undefined`, but I expected it to be the same as no expected type.

Comment: I expected `c => Int <: b <: String => undefined`, but maybe `Any => Int <: String => undefined` when you really need `_.toInt`, as someone commented. Anyway, for fun I asked on gitter.